RecyclerView error, Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionVideoViewHolder
so i know this is a pretty know error regarding recyclerview and yes i looked for solutions on previous posts but they are very specific for each case so i bring mine to the table. So this is my issue, i have some videos displayed in an activity and when i click one of them the screen goes white and checking the logcat, that error is being displayed.
error
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionVideoViewHolder{185e55e position=4 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap \[attachedScrap\] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{8a7ca2e VFED..... ......I. 0,755-1080,2001 #7f090240 app:id/profile_recycler_view}, adapter:com.example.tiktokclone.adapter.ProfileVideoAdapter@c9f49cf, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@d69af5c, context:com.example.tiktokclone.ProfileActivity@b956a9e
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:6156)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6339)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:572)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4255)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4010)
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1891)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1729)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1638)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:25388)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6466)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:4703)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3959)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2836)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10145)
 2024-09-16 18:58:47.525  5460-5460  AndroidRuntime          com.example.tiktokclone              E     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1406)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1415)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1015)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:945)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1389)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8674)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)

adapter code


class ProfileVideoAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<VideoModel>)
    :FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<VideoModel,ProfileVideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder>(options) {

    inner class VideoViewHolder(private val binding: ProfileVideoItemRowBinding) : ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(video:VideoModel){
            //mostrar el thumbnail desde el url del video
            Glide.with(binding.thumbnailImageView)
                .load(video.url)
                .into(binding.thumbnailImageView)
            binding.thumbnailImageView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(binding.thumbnailImageView.context, SingleVideoPlayerActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("videoId", video.id)
                binding.thumbnailImageView.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VideoViewHolder {
        val binding = ProfileVideoItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return VideoViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VideoViewHolder, position: Int, model: VideoModel) {
        holder.bind(model)
    }
}

Activity code:
class SingleVideoPlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivitySingleVideoPlayerBinding
    lateinit var adapter: ViewPagerAdapter
    lateinit var videoId: String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding  = ActivitySingleVideoPlayerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)

        videoId = intent.getStringExtra("videoId")!!
        setupViewPager()

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewPager() {
       val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<VideoModel>()
           .setQuery(
                Firebase.firestore.collection("videos").whereEqualTo("videoId",videoId),VideoModel::class.java
           ).build()
        adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(options)
        binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }


}

i tried several solutions regarding this problem but they all seem specific to each case

This only happens when there indeed is an inconsistency; eg. duplicate stable ID, IOOB, etc. See https://jonfhancock.com/get-threading-right-with-diffutil-423378e126d2
